# How to make a substitute function in a functional component jest enzyme

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

With jest, I want to check if the function is called and if the dispatch method is called in my functional component. I can't make the spy function because it is a functional component and I don't have access to  the instance object.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import styles from './style.module.scss';

const AddTask = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    const trimmedText = e.target.value.trim();
    if (e.which === 13 && trimmedText) {
      dispatch({ type: 'todoAdd', payload: trimmedText });
      e.target.value = '';
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <span className={styles.arrow} />
      <input
        className='new-todo'
        placeholder='What needs to be done?'
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddTask;


import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import AddTask from './AddTask';

jest.mock('react-redux');
let wrapper;

describe('Task:', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<AddTask />);
  });

  it('snapshot', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('called dispatch', () => {
    expect(useDispatch).toBeCalled(0);
  });
  it('called handleKeyDown fn', () => {
    wrapper.find('input').props().onKeyDown({ key: 'Enter' });
    const onKeyDown = jest.fn();
    expect(onKeyDown).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwvSh.png)
[Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLOBp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only mock the `useDispatch` hook, use [jest.requireActual(moduleName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename) method to require the original module to not be mocked.

Besides, you'd better use [.simulate(event[, mock]) => Self](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html#simulateevent-mock--self) method to simulate events on the node in the wrapper.

At the end, use `jest.resetAllMocks()` to reset all mocks.

E.g.

`AddTask.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const AddTask = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    const trimmedText = e.target.value.trim();
    if (e.which === 13 && trimmedText) {
      dispatch({ type: 'todoAdd', payload: trimmedText });
      e.target.value = '';
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input className="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddTask;
```

`AddTask.test.tsx`:

```
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import AddTask from './AddTask';

const mDispatch = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-redux', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('react-redux');
  return {
    ...originalModule,
    useDispatch: jest.fn(() => mDispatch),
  };
});

describe('Task:', () => {
  let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<AddTask />);
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('called handleKeyDown fn', () => {
    wrapper.find('input').simulate('keydown', { which: 13, target: { value: 'teresa teng' } });
    expect(useDispatch).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mDispatch).toBeCalledWith({ type: 'todoAdd', payload: 'teresa teng' });
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66328381/AddTask.test.tsx
  Task:
    ✓ called handleKeyDown fn (7 ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |     100 |       75 |     100 |     100 |                   
 AddTask.tsx |     100 |       75 |     100 |     100 | 9                 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.766 s, estimated 4 s
```

Comment: Thank you. It's work. But i have 1 error "The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables." I renamed mDispatch to mockDispatch and it working without errors.